# Out of bounds exception when I delete last row of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

If we have n rows in table and I delete row that its index is n-1, this code is Ok, but when I delete row that its index is n (or any row after row was deleted) I catch index out of bound exception! 
How can I resolve this problem?

```
 Thread registerThread = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            int i =JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(view, "Are you sure to delete these IP and port?" );
            if(i == 0){
                int selectedRow = workerMachineTable().getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println("selected row" + selectedRow);
                unRegister(selectedRow);
                dataModel.removeRow(selectedRow);
            }else return;
        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(view, e.getMessage(), "Error", 2);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger and see the values in real time...or print statements along the way works too.

Comment: If the last index is n-1 and you delete the n-th, it's standard behaviour...

Comment: by not trying to delete rows that don't exist. If your table has n rows, then n-1 is the maximal valid index. the indices start with 0, not 1

Comment: What is `view`? `model`? `view.getWorkerMachineTable()`?

Comment: i edit my code to simple format

Comment: IP list = [1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5]
port list =[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]

when select row 4 (IP = 1.2.3.4 & PORT = 6 ) to delete, output is =

selected row = 4
[1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]

when select row 4 again (IP = 1.2.3.5 & PORT = 7 ) that now have value of row 5  that is replace with it to delete output is =

selected row = -1

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Answer (score 0):

Subtract one from the selected row

```
  int selectedRow = view.getWorkerMachineTable().getSelectedRow() - 1;
```